# Image IsEnabled with Binding Property Does not work Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin forms -pcl v 2.3.4.267 -Debug on Android Device

I have an Image that is being used as button

```
          <Image Source="loginbutton.png"           
           Aspect="AspectFit"
           HorizontalOptions="Fill"
           Margin="50,20,50,0"
           fe:TappedGestureAttached.Command="{Binding Login}"
           IsVisible ="{Binding user.IsSubmitEnabled}"<---works fine
           IsEnabled="{Binding user.IsSubmitEnabled}"<---Does nothing
           />
```

as i mentioned in the code the Is Visible Works Great But Is Enabled does nothing.

note:-if there is any workaround please share it .

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: The Image  will be unclickable

Comment: At least as a workaround you could try the InputTransparent property

Comment: But it fails too with changes is  Bind value,  it behaves the same way as IsEnabled do.

Comment: I think you must handle it by youself... To the tap gesture doesn't matters if it is enabled or not... I usually create my own clicable image class, inheriting by image and exposing a command, then I handle this kind of thing inside a single class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Xamarin, already reported [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36703) and should be fixed in a future version of Xamarin.Forms, more specifically version **2.4.0-pre**.

As a Workaround you can use the IsSubmitEnabled as the parameter for the `CanExecute` parameter in your `Command`.

Something like this:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    Login = new Command(() => OnLogin(), () => IsSubmitEnabled);
}
```

But you will need to add a line `Login.CanExecute(null);` in your Property setter too.

```
private bool _isSubmitEnabled;
public bool IsSubmitEnabled
{
    get { return _isSubmitEnabled; }
    set
    {
        _isSubmitEnabled= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsSubmitEnabled));
        Login.CanExecute(null);
    }
}
```

This should work in the mean time. Till the fix is in production.

**Note**: just for information, this issue seems only to be happening on Android while on iOS seems to be working correctly.

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 0):

Are you using both statements in parallel?

```
IsVisible ="{Binding user.IsSubmitEnabled}"<---works fine
IsEnabled="{Binding user.IsSubmitEnabled}"<---Does nothing
```

Then IsEnabled=false is only active if the button is invisible, because both are binding to the same boolean property => IsSubmitEnabled.

Maybe you have to use a second boolean binding property?

Comment: no i tried each one alone the IsVisible works fine and changes its status according to the changes in the bind value but IsEnable and input Transparent values do not change according to the change in the bind values besides i am using IsEnable with Image .

Answer (score 0):

If you want unclickable when you enable property false you do as following

As First binding property of **IsVisible** and **IsEnable** must be different.

```
<Image Source="loginbutton.png"           
           Aspect="AspectFit"
           HorizontalOptions="Fill"
           Margin="50,20,50,0"
           fe:TappedGestureAttached.Command="{Binding Login}"
           IsVisible ="{Binding user.IsSubmitVisible}"
           IsEnabled="{Binding user.IsSubmitEnabled}"
           />
```

And you change the code in ViewModel like:

```
 public void Login()
    {
        If(IsSubmitEnabled){
           // Put your code here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/181845/#Comment_181845), if we bind IsEnabled property before binding commands, the properties wont' trigger. I ran in to same problem and moved IsEnabled binding after Command binding, and IsEnabled property was set correctly.

Hope that helps